# Post request with some simple parameters and an array

Tags: post, curl

How can I create a POST request with the following parameters using curl?

```
"person_id"
"address_data" : <ADDRESS> // look below what <ADDRESS> is

<ADDRESS>:
Array(
    street
    city
    zip_code
)
```

My problem is how to put this address_data which is supposed to be an array into the request.

```
curl.exe -d "module=website_api&action=add_addresses&person_id=123&address_data=XXXX>" MY_URL_HERE
```

I don't know what to put instead of XXXX.

Comment: You would make it a comma delimited list: `&address_data=street,city,zip_code` Then, in your server code, you would split the data on the comma and use the appropriate indexes to associate it to street, city, and zip_code.

Comment: @Shmiddty it is supposed to go like that: 'street'=>'abc'